# Custom TableView send parameter inSwift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm very new in Swift coding. I have experience in Android. So I know how can I do this is Andorid. It is like below;

```
public class MyUserProfileFragment extends BaseFragment {
    MyUserProfileAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new MyUserProfileAdapter(MyUserProfileFragment.this, getActivity());
    }
    public showDialog(){
        //do something
    }
}

public class MyUserProfileAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    MyUserProfileFragment fragmentMyUserProfile;
    Context context;
    public MyUserProfileAdapter(MyUserProfileFragment fragment, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.fragmentMyUserProfile = fragment;
    }
    fragmentMyUserProfile.showDialog();
}
```

So i can use all methods in MyUserProfileFragment from MyUserProfileAdapter.
But I can't do this in Swift. In Swift I have ;

```
class ViewControllerNewGame: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
        return cell
    }
    func showDialog(){
        //some actions
    }
}

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var img1: UIButton!
    @IBAction func click(sender: UIButton) {
        //I want to use showDialog method from ViewVoncontroller
    }
}
```

Those are very simle codes from my project. How can I use showDialog method in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method in ViewController :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewControllerNewGame.click(_:)),name:"click", object: nil)

func show(notification: NSNotification) {
        ViewControllerNewGame.click()
}
```

And use this method in `MyCustomCell` :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("click", object: nil)
```